Docx4j error while running in AWS lambda, It works fine in local machine
I have implemented conversion of docx file to pdf using Docx4j, its working well in my local machine and getting exceptions in aws lambda.

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: org.docx4j.fonts.fop.apps.FOPException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .docx4j (Read-only file system)

Please see this code
  Docx4jProperties.setProperty("docx4j.openpackaging.parts.TempDir", "/tmp");
            System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/tmp");
            String convertedFileName = "/tmp/templFile.pdf";
            File file = new File(convertedFileName);
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(contents);
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(convertedFileName);
            FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
            foSettings.setApacheFopMime(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF);
            foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
            Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, fout, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(convertedFileName);
            content = fin.readAllBytes();
            fin.close();
            file.delete();

i think lambda only allows to write files in  /tmp folder , so i have added that in code still not working.

at org.docx4j.fonts.IdentityPlusMapper.(IdentityPlusMapper.java:77)
Could not initialize class org.docx4j.fonts.IdentityPlusMapper: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.docx4j.fonts.fop.apps.FOPException:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .docx4j (Read-only file system)
adding some more log
